# Regex For money in CSV

Tags: java, regex

Hi have a csv file that contains numerous values. One thing it contains is a money column. An example of the file is:

```
...,...,...,$100,...,...
...,...,...,$2,500,...,...
```

I have seen regular expressions to grab money values out of each of these lines. However, my problem comes in because its a csv file and there is a comma in the money value.

My solution is to pre-process the file looking for money values that have the comma and simply remove them. However, I am having diffculty writing a regular expression to do this.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Regex for money? What's the going rate?

Comment: that's invalid CSV. `$2,500` in csv is two SEPARATE fields, one containing `$2`, and another containing `5000`. You should fix whatever's building this csv before you even TRY to parse it

Comment: Going off Marc B's comment, I would either switch the delimeter from commas to something you know won't be in any of your fields (like a pipe |  ) or don't write your dollar amounts with commas in them.

Comment: You better use the `;` separator.

Comment: As said above - the file is invalid CSV, but if the other fields are non-numeric, it's another story.

Comment: Yes, all other fields are non-numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this in Python, but it should work the same in Java:

```
r"\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)"
```

I believe you may need to double-down on the escape characters for Java. Breaking it down:

```py
\$  # match the dollar sign
(  # start group
  \d{1,3}  # match the first (or only) group of 1-3 digits,
  (?:  # start inner group, which we don't capture by itself
    ,  # match a comma
    \d{3}  # followed by three digits
  )*  # 0 or more of the inner group
)  # end expression
```

I tested this on the string `"...,$1,000,123,...$1"` and it returned matched groups `['1,000,123', '1']`. I hope that helps!

**Edit:**

It looks like you can get away with this in Java by replacing the single backslash characters in the above with a double backslash `"\\"`.

Also, as a comment stated, remove the `r` in front of the string for use in Java, so in Java the regex would be:

```
pattern = "\\$(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*)"
```

Comment: This is correct (also remove the r in front of the string). +1

Comment: what does ?: do?

Comment: @GoldenLion it makes it so that that group is not separately captured as its own group, but is captured as part of the outside group. I think. It's been a while since I've looked at this...

Comment: address =  "4502 150th Pl SE, Bellevue, WA 98006"
pattern= "([\w\s]*\,*(?:[\S]+))"   I thought the inner group would parse WA 98006 into separate elements. It does not.   I get three matches.  I was expecting five.  matches=re.findall(pattern,address)
for match in matches:
    print(match)

Comment: @GoldenLion I think that's my point. The `?:` makes that group recognize matching elements, but not parse them out as *separate* elements. They're just part of the outer group.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the *money* field is not followed by an integer field,
you could pull out the money value, then use a callback to replace the
comma's.

This matches just the errant comma's money field.

```
 # "\\$(?:\\d+(?:,\\d{3})+(?:\\.\\d*)?)"

 \$ 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?:
           ,
           \d{3} 
      )+
      (?: \. \d* )?
 )
```

This matches errant or not money field.

```
 # "\\$(?:\\d+(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)"

 \$ 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?:
           ,
           \d{3} 
      )*
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If all other fields are non-numeric, you can read whole file, match only commas between digits, and replace/remove them. You can use regex like:

```
(?<=\d)(,)(?=\d)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gD6bP2/1)